# Без учета регистра python

Tags: python

Имеется список зарегистрированных пользователей, как сделать чтоб при регистрации нового пользователя не учитывался регистр?:

```
current_users = ['admin', 'Eric', 'David', 'Michael', 'Raul']
new_users = ['Ravil', 'michael', 'raul']
for new_user in new_users:
    введите сюда кодif new_user in current_users:
        print("Unfortunately, this name " + new_user + " is already present in the system.")
    else:
        print("This name " + new_user + " is available.")
```

Comment: Приводить к одному регистру.

Comment: `if new_user.upper() in (current_user.upper() for current_user in current_users):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Приводить к одному регистру.

Например так:

```
current_users = ['admin', 'Eric', 'David', 'Michael', 'Raul']
new_users = ['Ravil', 'michael', 'raul']
...
current_users = [user.capitalize() for user in current_users]
new_users = [user.capitalize() for user in new_users]
...
```